# When I use request-promise in a function and return a value it says undefined

Tags: node.js, request

So from looking at the request-promise docs, here is what I have

```
function get_data_id(searchValue) {
    rp('http://example.com?data=searchValue')
    .then(function(response) {
        return JSON.parse(response).id;
    });
}
```

And then I use this code elsewhere in my script

`console.log(get_data_id(searchValue));`

However it returns `undefined`.

If I change `return JSON.parse(response).id` to `console.log(JSON.parse(response).id)` I get the following

```
undefined
valueofID
```

So the value I'm trying to return is definitely valid/correct, but I can't figure out how to return it as a value.

Answer (score 13):

You need to return the promise to the caller:

```
function get_data_id(searchValue) {
  return rp('http://example.com?data=searchValue')
    .then(function(response) {
      return JSON.parse(response).id;
    });
}
```

Then use your function like this:

```
get_data_id('hello').then(function (id) {
  console.log('Got the following id:', id)
})
```

Comment: thanks I was able to use this to send another request() as I was having trouble making a GET request then sending the returned body to a webhook with a POST request

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the request-promise will return a promise.

So if you directly console.log the return value, it will be undefined, because the promise has not yet been resolved.